# After countdown redirect to new page

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Html -->
<html lang="en">
<!-- Head -->
<head>
<title>Coming soon</title>
  <!-- Meta tags -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
  <!-- Meta tags -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /><!-- stylesheet -->      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script><!-- Supportive-JavaScript -->
 <!--fonts-->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
<!--/fonts-->
</head>
<!-- //Head -->
<!-- Body -->
  <body>
  <!-- main-section -->
    <div class="container clock">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="large-header" class="large-header">
                <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
                <div class="main-title">
                    <h1>Temperature Sensor <br /> coming soon</h1>
                    <div class="between"></div>
                    <p class="agileinfo txt-center"> &copy; Janneke 2018</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /main-section -->
  <!-- Counter required files -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/dscountdown.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dscountdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/clock.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){                     
            $('.between').dsCountDown({
                endDate: new Date("Januari 17, 2018 17:30:00"),
                theme: 'black'
                });                         
        });
    </script>
 <!-- //Counter required files -->
 <!-- particles effect -->
    <script src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        Particles.init({
          selector: '#myCanvas',
          color: '#6a446b',
          connectParticles: true,
          minDistance: 70
        });
      };
    </script>
<!-- //particles effect -->
</body>
<!-- //Body -->
</html>
<!-- //Html -->
```

How can i get a redirect in this code, tried alot of solutions from the internet even with the setTimeout, but when adding a setTimeout the page will only show the text Temperature Sensor coming soon but it wont show the time and date anymore, the page has an particle effect but i need to know how to get an redirect in the countdown part.

Anybody that can gelp me to get it redirecting to a new page

Comment: new Date("Januari 17, 2018 17:30:00")

as soon as the timer reaches that day and time it should redirect to a new website, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather is that you are struggling to redirect your page at the end of the countdown?

You've missed a property method `onFinish` in your countdown script. It goes like this:

```
onFinish: function(){
    window.location = "https://www.google.com";
}
```

I've set up a sample application based on your code here, which redirects to google after 1 minute: https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/a6dhjs2y/1/

Hope this helps?

Comment: this helped alot, thanks alot for the help, anything i can do with the 0-1 time that i get?

Comment: what 0-1 time are you gettting?

Comment: when timer reaches 0 it goes to 0-1 and then redirects to the new page

Comment: I don't actually see that :s I see the countdown reach 1 and then redirect

Answer (score 0):

A piece of code of how I do it, I hope it's going to help you.

```
    window.setTimeout(function(){

       // Move to a new location or you can do something else
       window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";

    }, 5000);
```

Comment: but how will i add it to the countdown code, cause i tried it several ways but it wont redirect or even takes away the countdown

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you can use the onFinish option of the dsCountdown plugin.

```
$('.between').dsCountDown({
    endDate: new Date("Januari 17, 2018 17:30:00"),
    theme: 'black',
    onFinish: function() {
        window.location.assign('http://your-page.it');
    }
});
```

I found this option (`onFinish`) in the dsCountdown library, here:
https://github.com/iwayanwirka/dscountdown/blob/master/dscountdown.js

Comment: this will redirect right away, anyhting i am doing wrong?

Comment: the assign part didnt work with the script, but u were very close aswell with, thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: You can also use `window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in'`, there's not so much difference.